# chrome extension options change value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a question for writing options of chrome extension.I get the date from value but if i want to change it. It doesn't work.
for example: i get 2017/01/01 in date. I chage the date[0] and date[1].
The console log still print 2017/01/01.
So, how to change the value i get. Thanks

```
  function save_options() {
  var start = document.getElementById('selectStartStation').value;
  var destination = document.getElementById('selectDestinationStation').value;
  var date = document.getElementById('bookdate').value;
  var time = document.getElementById('toTimeTable').value;
  if(date.length<10){
     alert("error")
     return false;
   }
    date[0]=0;
    date[1]=0;


  console.log(date);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    selectStartStation:start,
    selectDestinationStation :destination,
    toTimeTable:time,
    bookdate:date
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    alert("success");
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}
```

Comment: your code does not show a console log after the modification.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Other than the `chrome.storage.sync.set()`, which does not appear to be what you are asking about, this could be placed into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). At a minimum, we need the HTML, your input value, and what you expected output (*exactly*, not just that you expect it to be changed)

Comment: What do you intend to be doing with `date[0]=0;` and `data[0]=0]`? Are you trying to modify the `date` string which you got from the value of the `bookdate` element? If so, it will not work, strings in JavaScript are immutable (e.g. you can not change individual characters).

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer from your reply. It is my first time to ask a question. Do I  need to edit the question for correct format or just follow the rule next time?